# Problema generando .JAR en VSCode

Tags: java, vscode, jar

Estoy desarrollando un programa en lenguaje Java con VSCode. El código compila y funciona perfectamente, pero a la hora de generar el archivo .JAR con la extensión *JAR Builder v1.1.1* del Marketplace de VSCode resulta que obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> `error: invalid flag: c:\Users\fran-\Documents\1.Importante\VSCode_related\TXRXSPJavaForAssembly\txrxsp\*`

Tengo todas las variables necesarias en PATH y tanto el JDK como el JRE actualizados a su última versión. Intenté de todo y cuando ejecuto en CMD el comando: `javac --help`, la sugerencia que creo que puedo llegar a utilizar es el comando `javac -J<flag>` pero no estoy seguro ni de cómo usarlo ni para qué sirve...

---

### EDIT

Añado información útil:

- Trabajo con Windows 10 x64bits.
- Tengo el JDK en su versión 14.
- Tengo el JRE en su versión 1.8.0
- Tengo javac en su versión 14.

Dejo una captura de la estructura de carpetas para este proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He migrado de Eclipse a VSCode hace poco y simplemente he creado un folder y allí creé una clase *.java* donde está todo el código. Es un programa de una sola clase y bastante simple justamente para probar estas funcionalidades de VSCode y amigarme un poco más con él. ¿Debo crear proyectos de otra forma?

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: pusiste "c:\Users\fran-\Documents\1.Importante\VSCode_related\TXRXSPJavaForAssembly\txrxsp\*" entre comillas?

Comment: Sí, pero no dio resultado

Comment: Segun esto las opciones -J en javac son para decirle a javac cómo usar la maquina virtual de java. Nunca he hecho eso. Y no se porqué sería necesario reconfigurar el compilador de esa manera.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269302/java-compiler-options-j

No es claro aquí lo que estás haciendo o qué parametros estás enviando.. debes dar más información.

Comment: incluye por favor tu estructura de carpetas (de preferencia la salida del comando tree), tu sistema operativo, versión de javac, versión de java y cualuiqer otra información relevante para que podamos reproducir tu problema, porque en mi máquina funciona bien.

Comment: Acabo de añadir la información que me has pedido, espero que sirva

Comment: Intenta pasar todo tu código a una carpeta sin caracteres especiales como c:/codigo, lo que sale de invalid flag se me figura que es porque `c:\Users\fran-` termina en guión y lo que sigue después se interpreta como un flag.

Answer (score 0):

Todo estaba bien seteado (JDK, JRE, variables PATH, etc.), el problema fue que la extensión *JAR Builder* de VSCode está en fase de desarrollo y aún no puede generar archivos .jar de un proyecto que trabaje con librerías externas e imágenes.