# The import org.jdom2 cannot be resolved Visual Studio Code java

Tags: java, vscode, libreria, java-import, jdom

Me he descargado la librería jdom2 para poder trabajar con ella en java. He guardado la descarga en la carpeta lib y al tratar de importar esta para usarla me salta el error ya mencionado en el titulo. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? ¿Cómo se incorpora la libreía al proyecto de forma correcta?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EDIT: Así es como la importo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tal vez estas tratando de importarla de manera correcta, te sugiero nos muestres como es que tratas de importarla para que este disponible en tu classpath

Comment: He adjuntado como realizo el import @RuslanLópez

Comment: te recomiendo usar [tag:maven] para evitar los problemas del inicpiente plugin de java para vscode https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/366747/problema-generando-jar-en-vscode

Comment: Le echaré un vistazo, gracias @RuslanLópez